# How to Make Application to Wake Computer From Sleep

Tags: language-agnostic, hibernation

I know several alarm clock programs already do this for your computer. I also know you can do this in task scheduler manually.

I want to write a Java, C++, C#, or Python program to do this. I just don't know where to begin and am struggling to find decent resources. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See ["java wake computer from sleep"](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+wake+computer+from+sleep&oq=java+wake+computer+from+sleep); substitute your favorite language, and possibly your relevant platform.

Comment: _I just don't know where to begin_ Choosing a language would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Try using java Robot.

The Robot class simulates user interaction with the computer. I know for a fact that it will prevent a computer from locking/going to sleep.

Try to set the Thread.sleep() to the amount of time you want the computer to sleep/wake up.

Good luck!